# Wordpress templates not available when chnanging page template

Tags: wordpress, templates, themes, block

Using wordpress 6.2.2 i have developed simple block theme with few templates.

```
my-theme
  - templates
    - Index.html
    - Page.html
    - Home.html
    - Single.html
  - theme.json
  .......
```

When I try to change a page template, I cannot see any of templates already created in the popup.

[image]

But I can see them under templates.

[image]

Can some help me to fix the issue.

Thank you,
Sudheera